# play a .sdp file describing a UDP/RTP H264 stream iOS 8+

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, gstreamer, h.264, rtp

I´m looking into how to implement a simple app that can play a .sdp file (like VLC can do) in order to open a RTP stream made by GStreamer:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rpicamsrc bitrate=10000000 ! video/x-h264,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1  ! h264parse config-interval=1 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.100.123 port=1234
```

What would be the easiest way to do this in Swift/Objecvtive-C? Are there any built in functions or libraries I should know of?

Answer (score 0):

You should give a look at openRTSP:

http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/